# Simple PHP App Failing to Start on ECS With Docker Compose and NGINX

Tags: docker, nginx, amazon-ecs

I have a very simple PHP app built using Docker Compose using NGINX and Busybox. It's working fine locally but I can't get it to start up properly in its container on AWS ECS. The app structure is as follows:

```
Root
--conf
  nginx.conf
  php.ini
  supervisord.conf
--logs
--sites
  default.vhost
--www
  --default
    index.php
aws-compose.yml
docker-compose.yml
Dockerfile
```

The important files are:

aws-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
 services:

  web:
    image: nginx:alpine
    cpu_shares: 100
    mem_limit: 262144000
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    links:
      - php
    volumes:
      - /sites:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - /conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    volumes_from:
      - code

  php:
    image: '195367337191.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/myapp-php-dev:rv1'
    cpu_shares: 100
    mem_limit: 262144000
    build: .
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes_from:
      - code

   code:
    image: busybox
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - /www:/var/www
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm

RUN pecl install xdebug
RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

COPY conf/php.ini /etc/php/7.1/fpm/conf.d/40-custom.ini
```

Conf/nginx.conf:

```
user root;
worker_processes 1;
# daemon off;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;

  keepalive_timeout 65;

  gzip on;

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*;
}
```

Conf/php.ini:

```
; Enable XDebug
zend_extension = xdebug.so

; XDebug configuration
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.renite_enable = 1
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "/var/log"
date.timezone = "America/New_York"
; Show PHP errors
display_errors = 1
```

Conf/supervisord.conf:

[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

```
[program:nginx]
command = /usr/sbin/nginx
user = root
autostart = true

[program:php7-fpm]
command = /usr/sbin/php-fpm7.0 -FR
user = root
autostart = true
```

Sites/default.vhost:

```
server {
  server_name default;
  root        /var/www/default;
  index       index.html index.php;

  client_max_body_size 100M;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 1800;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires       max;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log    off;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files     $uri =404;
    include       fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass  php:9000;
  }
}
```

The issue seems to be with the references in the volumes section of the "web" service in aws-compose.yml as when I remove them completely the container starts but shows the default Nginx "needs configuration" holding page. With them in-situ as below:

```
    volumes:
      - /sites:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - /conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

I get the following error in the tasks section of AWS ECS under "stopped":

Status reason   CannotStartContainerError: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:424: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\"/conf/nginx.conf\\" to rootfs \\"

For info in my local docker-compose.yml file the references are as follows:

```
  - ./sites:/etc/nginx/conf.d
  - ./conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

But this errors when I spin it up on AWS stating the syntax doesn't conform with the required RegEx pattern.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Dons anyone got an answer?